# record audio, store on Firebase, and play audio | Flutter - Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage, flutter-audioplayers

I aimed to record audio, save it to Firebase storage, and then retrieve and play it on the Home Screen. To accomplish this, I followed these steps.

**For Upload file** :

```
Future<String> storeAudio(String recordFilePath) async {
  String downloadURL = "failed";
  File audioFile = File(recordFilePath);
  Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref('try/')
      .child('/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}');

  try {
    SettableMetadata metadata = SettableMetadata(contentType: 'audio/mpeg');
    await reference.putFile(audioFile, metadata);
    downloadURL = await reference.getDownloadURL();
    print("Upload complete, File URL: $downloadURL");
  } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
    print("Failed to upload audio: ${e.message}");
  } catch (e) {
    print("An unexpected error occurred: $e");
  }

  return downloadURL;
}
```

**It saves like this**:

[image]

**Download URL of audio** : [this](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rotaract-debate.appspot.com/o/try%2F1699343040392.mp3?alt=media&token=af9657b6-e495-4165-922d-015668b9fcc7&_gl=1*2szvco*_ga*NzI2NjMxMDE3LjE2ODU3Njg1OTY.*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY5OTMzMjkyNS4zNDEuMS4xNjk5MzQ0MDU0LjYwLjAuMA..)

---

Now, I tried to play in Home Screen using `audioplayers: ^5.1.0` flutter package

**Play Audio** :

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
await audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(
          'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rotaract-debate.appspot.com/o/try%2F1699343040392.mp3?alt=media&token=af9657b6-e495-4165-922d-015668b9fcc7&_gl=1*ikbc29*_ga*NzI2NjMxMDE3LjE2ODU3Njg1OTY.*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY5OTMzMjkyNS4zNDEuMS4xNjk5MzQ0MDU2LjU4LjAuMA..'));
```

**It shows erorr** -

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(AndroidAudioError, Failed to set source. For troubleshooting, see: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/troubleshooting.md, MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN {what:1}, MEDIA_ERROR_SYSTEM, null)

**But, It works properly on another URLs like this** "https://listringtones.com/tones/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/2bewafaa-tu.mp3"

What's the wrong?

Comment: Did you check your firebase policies? Sounds like firebase is blocking the connection

Comment: yes, and I tried to play it using web page (JS). it works.